# logout when tab or browser window closed jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I am new @jsp, and would like to call the logout function when the tab or the browser window is closed. i've made some research and found out that i need to use window.onbeforeunload. But the thing is , i don't know where to put it in my jsp page. Here is it's code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1256"
    pageEncoding="windows-1256"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1256">

       <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt" prefix="c" %>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt"  prefix="fmt" %>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
        <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core-rt" prefix="c-rt" %>   

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css">
<title>Insert title here</title>

   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" runat="server">
     var divSelected = null;
     function switchURL()  
     {  
          var x = document.getElementById("femp").value;
              <c:choose>  
                     <c:when test="${puser.LOGIN==true}">
                       document.getElementById("temp").value = x;
                  //     alert("${puser.LOGIN}");
                     </c:when>  
                     <c:otherwise>  
                       document.getElementById("temp").value = 0;
                       document.getElementById("femp").value = 0;
                      //   alert("${puser.LOGIN}");
                     </c:otherwise>
                    </c:choose>        


     }  
</script>




   <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" runat="server">
     var divSelected = null;
       function Logout()  
     {  
        document.getElementById("Form1").target  ="";
        document.getElementById("Form1").action  = "/dcHR/login";
   //   window.location = "login";


     }  





</script>

</head>
<body>
 <section class="container">
    <div class="login">

<form id="Form1" action="http://localhost:80/reports/rwservlet" method="Post"  target="_blank">

 <input type="hidden" id="cmdkey" name="cmdkey" value="repserv">
  <input type="hidden" id="temp" name="P_TO_EMP" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" id="femp" name="P_FROM_EMP" value="${puser.USR_USER}" > 
    <input type="hidden" id="pcomp" name="P_COMP" value="${puser.USR_CP}">
    <p> Years:<input type="text"  name="P_YEAR"> </p>
    <p> Month:<input type="text"  name="P_PERIOD"> </p>
           <input type="submit" value="Report"  name="pbtn" onclick="switchURL()" />
           <input type="submit" value="Logout" name="pbtn"  onclick="Logout()"/>

</form>


  </div>


  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

can somebody help me plz.

Regards to all.

Comment: concept of using `onbeforeunload` for this is not practical as there are numerous reasons it will not fire....user power fail, no internet connection , browser crash etc

Answer (score 0):

You have to add listener on window object as below

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
    //Ajax call to invoke logout action
});
```

Put this code in your jsp page.

Comment: i added it to the bloc <script> </script> and nothing happens:

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" runat="server">
     var divSelected = null;
       function Logout()  
     {  
        document.getElementById("Form1").target  ="";
        document.getElementById("Form1").action  = "/dcHR/login";
       }  
       window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
          return "If you close the window, your application with still be running. If you wish to stop the application, click 'cancel' and ";
         });
       </script>

Comment: Add Logout() function call inside beforeunload event handler as shown below                                                      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(){
    Logout();
});                                                                                              confirmation from user will be handled by browser since alert, confirm and prompt methods of window will be ignored during this event.

Comment: The thing is , i am not sure if it's passing by the code under window.addEventListener. the Logout function, redirect the page to /dchr/login, and puts target ="". then executes a certain code in a class that extends HttpServlet.
How can i be able to execute that code without passing by the redirection to /dchr/login. Knowing that the browser will be already closed.
Thank again for your precious help.